# Запятые между обстоятельствами

Tags: пунктуация

И снова предложение на то же правило. Нужны ли эти запятые?!

Я думаю, что мало кто их не знает: возможно, это и бедность, не позволявшая когда-то(,) в окружении идейных врагов(,) выделять достаточные средства для развития науки и техники, это и долгое время пребывания у власти в стране людей, по многим причинам отвергавших генетику и кибернетику (эти величайшие в истории человечества инновации!) и примерно так же относящихся к работе изобретателей, это почти 15 лет морального и материального развала страны в период смены экономической формации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При перечислении лучше использовать точку с запятой (большая распространенность, собственные знаки препинания:

Я думаю, что мало кто их не знает: возможно, это и бедность, не позволявшая когда-то, в окружении идейных врагов, выделять достаточные средства для развития науки и техники; это и долгое время пребывания у власти в стране людей, по многим причинам отвергавших генетику и кибернетику (эти величайшие в истории человечества инновации!) и примерно так же относящихся к работе изобретателей; это почти 15 лет морального и материального развала страны в период смены экономической формации.

Comment: Спасибо. Предложение стало выглядеть намного лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Аленка, ну почему "инновации"? Кашшмар какой... Во времена гонений на генетику и кибернетику "инноваций" еще не было... зуб даю... Может, подобрать другое слово? А то сразу впечатление, что пишет "менеджер"... В смысле - офисный планктон...

Да и "величайшие в истории" - сказать вряд ли можно. Ну, генетика, ну, кибернетика...

Comment: Это, наверное, потому, что человек с этим связан, технарь, а когда говоришь о деле своей жизни и о том, что с ним связано, становится понятно, что это для тебя самое главное.

Answer (score 0):

Запятые в скобках факультативны.